# Unable to import torch

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I installed CPU version of pytorch using this:

```
conda install pytorch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0 cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Unfortunately when I import using this:

```
import torchvision
```

It gives following error

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6dd351122000> in <module>
----> 1 import torchvision

c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\torchvision\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from .extension import _HAS_OPS
      5 
----> 6 from torchvision import models
      7 from torchvision import datasets
      8 from torchvision import ops

c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .alexnet import *
      2 from .resnet import *
      3 from .vgg import *
      4 from .squeezenet import *
      5 from .inception import *

c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\alexnet.py in <module>
----> 1 import torch
      2 import torch.nn as nn
      3 from .utils import load_state_dict_from_url
      4 
      5 

c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py in <module>
    115                 err = ctypes.WinError(last_error)
    116                 err.strerror += f' Error loading "{dll}" or one of its dependencies.'
--> 117                 raise err
    118             elif res is not None:
    119                 is_loaded = True

OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "c:\users\fatima.arshad\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

I had anaconda2 installed after which I downloaded and installed anaconda3 and used the above statement. My python now is 3.8.

Comment: From the error, it looks like it is still using anaconda2 instead of anaconda3. Make sure you uninstall the redundant one